# Arduino/Arduino clone board suggestions

Tags: arduino-due, arduino-yun

I am planning to buy a Arduino board. I am also considering Arduino clones, too. My requirements are that the board should inbuilt communication modes like Ethernet, WiFi and a SD card slot, too. Also the board should have a decent amount of memory and the processor must be a a little more powerful than the Uno. The board must be capable of running a OS if possible!

I was looking at the Yun and Due. The Yun has all the communication modes but runs on a low end processor. The Due on the other hand runs on a ARM processor but has none of the communication modes. So now I am in a fix.

**Which board should I choose?**

Comment: Wait... [the Uno can run Linux!!!](http://hackaday.com/2012/03/28/building-the-worst-linux-pc-ever/) Also, it's not a clone (and probably not on topic for this site) if it's not a replica of an official Arduino board.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a Yun. Despite having a low end CPU, it runs at 400MHz and the disk space can be expanded using the uSD card (see [this blog post](http://blog.arduino.cc/2014/05/06/time-to-expand-your-yun-disk-space-and-install-node-js/)).

If you don't plan to make CPU intensive tasks (such as real time video streaming and manipulation), the Yun is a nice tool. Otherwise, the Tre fits better (however, at the time of writing, it [still has to be released](http://blog.arduino.cc/2014/05/13/arduino-tre-developer-edition/)).

Comment: Can the YUN do multitaking ? Also do you have any ideas about arduino clones ?

Comment: @cache No, no Arduino board can do hardware multithreading AFAIK... [You can do software multithreading...](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/asynchronous-function-calls-in-arduino-sketch/1814#1814) Also, it's not a clone if it's not a replica of an official Arduino board. Therefore, asking for a clone is the same thing as asking for a board.

Comment: The Yun can do multitasking on the Linux side only.

Comment: @FedericoFissore - untrue.  Multitasking is a software feature.  Things like having lots of memory, protection modes, or virtual cores etc certainly make it easier, but it's ultimately a function of the software, not the hardware.

Comment: @ChrisStratton agree. I thought cache was actually talking about multithreading (executing two different codes at the same time)

Comment: @all : My apologies. I wanted to do multithreading. So to execute that one would need the hardware capable to perform the task.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin : Yes i do understand what a clone means and i do have some clones too. These clones have the same architecture as the original but with added features.

Coming to the part where a UNO running linux , really ? It says here that "_it takes two hours to boot up to a bash prompt, and four more to load up Ubuntu and login_" If starting itself takes this much time, then when will i run my programs ?

Comment: @cache No, you're talking about a *derivative*. A clone is pretty much an exact duplicate (with a few *minor* changes). As far as the Linux computer, I wasn't saying it is viable, only that it is possible.

Comment: So as of now my best bet would be to get a YUN , right ?