# How to integrate smoothing into project (HVAC thermostat / controller)

Tags: programming

I am working on building a "simple" HVAC thermostat. This is my current sketch.

```
    // include the libraries for gizmos
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht11.h>

dht11 DHT11; // Figure out what this line does
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2); // initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins

// These constants won't change:
const int ACledPin = 8;      // Air Conditioner LED (RED)
const int HTledPin = 9;      // Heat LED (YELLOW)
const int threshold = 77;    // an arbitrary threshold level that's in the range of the analog input

const int RELAY_01 = 6;    // RELAY 1 PIN 9
const int RELAY_02 = 10;   // RELAY 2 PIN 10

void setup() {
  DHT11.attach(7);       // Attach DHT11 sensor to pin 7
  lcd.begin(16, 2);      // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  Serial.begin(9600);    // Serial setup

  pinMode(ACledPin, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 8 as output
  pinMode(HTledPin, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 9 as output
  pinMode(RELAY_01, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 6 as output
  pinMode(RELAY_02, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 10 as output

  // Leaves the relays in default "off" (no noise/click)
  digitalWrite(RELAY_01, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RELAY_02, HIGH);

}

void loop() {

  float analogValue = (DHT11.fahrenheit()); // trying to set up the temp reading as an int variable
////////////// if then ////////////////
// if the analog value is high enough, turn on the LED:
  if (analogValue > threshold) {
    digitalWrite(ACledPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(HTledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_01, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_02, LOW);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(ACledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(HTledPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_01, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_02, HIGH);
  }


Serial.println(analogValue);  // print the analog value:

// Set up the LCD Stuff
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);      // Set cursor to top left
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(analogValue, 1);
  lcd.print("F");

  delay(1000);

}
```

I want to add "smoothing" to the temperature reading. I Found this tutorial http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Smoothing and have it working the way I want it.

```
// Define the number of samples to keep track of.  The higher the number,
// the more the readings will be smoothed, but the slower the output will
// respond to the input.  Using a constant rather than a normal variable lets
// use this value to determine the size of the readings array.
#include <dht11.h>
dht11 DHT11; // Figure out what this line does

const int numReadings = 5;

float readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int index = 0;                    // the index of the current reading
float total = 0;                  // the running total
float average = 0;                // the average

void setup()
{
  DHT11.attach(7);       // Attach DHT11 sensor to pin 7
  Serial.begin(9600);    // initialize serial communication with computer:
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) readings[thisReading] = 0; // initialize all the readings to 0:       
}

void loop() {
  // subtract the last reading:
  total= total - readings[index];         
  // read from the sensor:  
  readings[index] = (DHT11.fahrenheit()); //analogRead(inputPin); 
  // add the reading to the total:
  total= total + readings[index];       
  // advance to the next position in the array:  
  index = index + 1;                    

  // if we're at the end of the array...
  if (index >= numReadings)              
    // ...wrap around to the beginning: 
    index = 0;                           

  // calculate the average:
  average = total / numReadings;         
  // send it to the computer as ASCII digits
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Realtime: ");
  Serial.println(DHT11.fahrenheit(),2);
  Serial.print("Average:  ");
  Serial.println(average);   
  delay(2000);        // delay in between reads for stability            
}
```

I'm new to Arduino and don't know the best way to do this. I'm not certain how to do multiple loops/delays in a single project, or if I even need to.

EDIT:

I've ended up with this based on the comments from @Craig. The only thing that needs some adjustment are the first 4 readings are low, so it would be nice to somehow ignore, probably not a big deal in the long run.

Example readings on startup;

```
Realtime: 77.00
Average:  15.40

Realtime: 77.00
Average:  30.80

Realtime: 77.00
Average:  46.20

Realtime: 77.00
Average:  61.60

Realtime: 77.00
Average:  77.00
```

Final code

```
// include the libraries for gizmos
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <dht11.h>

dht11 DHT11; // Figure out what this line does
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2); // initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins

// These constants won't change:
const int ACledPin = 8;      // Air Conditioner LED (RED)
const int HTledPin = 9;      // Heat LED (YELLOW)
const int threshold = 77;    // an arbitrary threshold level that's in the range of the analog input

const int RELAY_01 = 6;    // RELAY 1 PIN 9
const int RELAY_02 = 10;   // RELAY 2 PIN 10



// START ADDITIONS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const int numReadings = 5;
float readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int index = 0;                    // the index of the current reading
float total = 0;                  // the running total


float get_smoothed_temp() {
    total = total - readings[index]; // remove oldest reading
    readings[index] = DHT11.fahrenheit();
    total += readings[index];
    index = (index + 1) % numReadings;

    return (total / numReadings);
}
// END ADDITIONS ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {
  DHT11.attach(7);       // Attach DHT11 sensor to pin 7
  lcd.begin(16, 2);      // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  Serial.begin(9600);    // Serial setup
  for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) readings[thisReading] = 0; // initialize all the readings to 0:

  pinMode(ACledPin, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 8 as output
  pinMode(HTledPin, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 9 as output
  pinMode(RELAY_01, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 6 as output
  pinMode(RELAY_02, OUTPUT);  // initialize pin 10 as output

  // Leaves the relays in default "off" (no noise/click)
  digitalWrite(RELAY_01, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(RELAY_02, HIGH);

}

void loop() {

  float analogValue = (get_smoothed_temp()); // trying to set up the temp reading as an int variable
////////////// if then ////////////////
// if the analog value is high enough, turn on the LED:
  if (analogValue > threshold) {
    digitalWrite(ACledPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(HTledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_01, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_02, LOW);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(ACledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(HTledPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_01, LOW);
    digitalWrite(RELAY_02, HIGH);
  }


Serial.println(analogValue);  // print the analog value:

// Set up the LCD Stuff
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);      // Set cursor to top left
  lcd.print("Real F:");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("AVG  F:");
  lcd.print(analogValue, 1);


  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: What's the difference between the relay pins in the HT/AC pins?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is replace your call to `DHT11.fahrenheit()` with a call to a new function (e.g. get_smoothed_temp()) that keeps track of the last several readings and returns the smoothed value.

```
const int numReadings = 5;
float readings[numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int index = 0;                    // the index of the current reading
float total = 0;                  // the running total

float get_smoothed_temp() {
    total = total - readings[index]; // remove oldest reading
    readings[index] = DHT11.fahrenheit();
    total += readings[index];
    index = (index + 1) % numReadings;

    return (total / numReadings);
}
```

You will still need to set the readings array to all zeros in the setup function.

Answer (score 3):

Your running average code is fine.

A quick way to start up fast is to take your first reading in setup, and fill the array with that value instead of zero.  That way you always get a reasonable temperature from the smoothing, it just gradually drifts from the first reading to the average of multiple readings  (rather than from 0 - a bogus value - to the that average).

This can work for the exponential smoothing too (old average = first reading).

An alternative is to only average as many samples as you have put into the array (1 then 2, then 3 etc until it's filled).  That takes extra code to handle just the first few results, tho, and the simpler approach suggested above (initially fill the array with a legitimate reading) is usually fine.

Comment: Good idea. I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not certain how to do multiple loops/delays in a single project

You *can't* do this.* [Software threading](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/286/how-can-i-create-multiple-running-threads) is the only way to do something like what you want, but it's too complex for what you need. What you want is to use the `millis()` function to return the time and

```
// constants won't change. Used here to 
// set pin numbers:
const int ledPin =  13;      // the number of the LED pin

// Variables will change:
int ledState = LOW;             // ledState used to set the LED
long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated

// the follow variables is a long because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to blink (milliseconds)

void setup() {
  // set the digital pin as output:
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);      
}

void loop()
{
  // here is where you'd put code that needs to be running all the time.

  // check to see if it's time to blink the LED; that is, if the 
  // difference between the current time and last time you blinked 
  // the LED is bigger than the interval at which you want to 
  // blink the LED.
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED 
    previousMillis = currentMillis;   

    // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
    if (ledState == LOW)
      ledState = HIGH;
    else
      ledState = LOW;

    // set the LED with the ledState of the variable:
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  }
}
```

You can then pull button changes while you wait for a new reading. Another way would be to use an *interrupt* to interrupt the flow of the program when a button changes. I won't get into that.

For your use, you can use this template I made:

```
long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time temp was updated
long interval = 1000;           // interval at which to check the temp (milliseconds)

void setup() {
  //Foobar
}

void loop()
{
  //Bar of foo
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;   
    //Check Temp
  }
}
```

*<sub>Not to be confused with the `loop` statement.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I've just done a fan controller (using digital sensors - DS18b20, in my case) and chose an exponential average for smoothing the readings because it doesn't require storing or managing old data and I could get the smoothing I needed. During setup I took a reading from each sensor and preset the averages to those values. That gives the system a "running start"; it doesn't need to wait for enough samples for the averages to settle.

The exponential average I chose was `(3 * oldAverage + tempr)/4` because it gave the performance I needed and is easy and fast to calculate without floating point. Multiplying by 3 is done by shifting and adding; dividing by 4 is done by shifting.

Here's the routine I used. It could easily be put in-line; the compiler probably will:

```
int16_t xpavg(int16_t tempr, int16_t oldAverage)
{
   // (3*oldavg + 1*tempr)/4
   return( (((oldAverage<<1) + oldAverage + tempr) + 2) >> 2 );
}
```